# Share Google Analytics data excluding Google Adsense data

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

I have a Google Analytics provide linked with my Google Adsense profile.

I want to share the Google Analytics data with some other users (I believe I'm permitted to do that by Google ToS), but I want to exclude Google Adsense data (both because they have no need to know, and because I'm not sure it is permitted by Google ToS).

Is there any way to selectively set permissions to Google Analytics data when adding users to a Google Analytics account?

E.g., can I add somebody with the capability to see Audience and Traffic Sources views, but not Content / Adsense views?

I found a semi-relevant link at Google but this seems to remove it from the whole view, and also doesn't work as I cannot find the Data Sources. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/98145

I don't want to flat-out remove the Adsense integration as that means I as an administrator lose this data myself (and possibly it is still visible in the view I'm sharing, not sure).

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find a solution?